# Calling async method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have a controller with something like the following:

```
public MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations();
        return Json(new { success = successful }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When calling my controller I get the following error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations
>      may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain
>      events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page,
>      ensure that the Page is marked `<%@ Page Async="true" %>`.

Now I dont have control over `CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations` and the method itself is not async but internally does some async fire and forget. What can I do to fix it? Have tried to change the controller to an `AsyncController` and/or making the method in the controller async.

Edit:

When I attempted to use an AsyncController I first tried, with the same result

```
public MyController : AsyncController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations();
        return Json(new { success = successful }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And then

```
public MyController : AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething()
    {
        CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations();
        return Json(new { success = successful }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Which did change the exception to the following "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."

Comment: Can you show your AsyncController version? *Is* this occurring while executing a page?

Comment: It happens when CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations is called in the controller.

The version is dll the AsyncController is the following Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0 - System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: Yes, but is this in the context of a page? And again, please can you show the attempt you made to use this an an AsyncController?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by in the context of a page, the method is called from javascript and should return some Json, all standard MVC and routes :)

Comment: Right, so it sound like it's *not* in the context of a page - whereas if this were a non-AJAX request (a whole page request), it easily could be.

Comment: Please provide more details about this `CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations` method. Why does it require page with async="true"? What infrastructure does it use? Does it depend on some generic handlers? How does it fire those async operations? Is it tied to an ASP.NET infrastructure or could it be used in a different type of application as well? Does it use TPL, ThreadPool, manual Threads, ...

Comment: It uses `async` and `await` eg TPL internally, and it is used in other applications as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Now I dont have control over CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations and the method itself is not async but internally does some async fire and forget. What can I do to fix it?

Contact the person who wrote it and make *them* fix it.

Seriously, that's the best option. There's no good fix for this - only a hack.

You can hack it to work like this:

```
public MyController : Controller
{
  public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething()
  {
    await Task.Run(() => CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations());
    return Json(new { success = successful }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

**This is not recommended.** This solution pushes off work to a background thread, so when the `async` operations resume, they will not have an `HttpContext`, etc. This solution completes the request while there is still processing to be done. This solution will not behave correctly if the server is stopped/recycled at just the wrong time.

There is only one proper solution: change `CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I agree it has to change.

The async work is not important though its just a notification to another system which does not matter if it is lost or not. All the important work is done synchronous.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If CallSomeMethodWhichDoesAsyncOperations() does not need HttpContext and it is properly stateless, then both of your arguments for changing it do not hold up.  In fact, the async method may well be expensive and returning from the controller action before the async method completes may well be an excellent design decision.

Comment: I disagree. Running code independent from a request is extremely dangerous, [as Phil Hacck points out](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx). This is still fully true if the operation is stateless. Also, if the `async` method is expensive (assuming you mean CPU-intensive), wrapping it in `Task.Run` will *decrease* efficiency, not *increase* it.

Comment: I don't think there's a clear set of options for solution.  In the case of a fire and forget stateless operation (e.g. your controller calls a business layer method that in turn drops a Service Bus queue message using the async API). How do you solve that?

Comment: @ThiagoSilva: I'm not sure if I follow your question. Could you post your own question?

Comment: @StephenCleary I think the only way to go here is to change the CallSomeMethodWHichDoesAsync() so that instead of awaiting, it calls the async method followed by a .ContinueWith() that does whatever else would have been done in the code after the task completes.  This allows callers to call the method as a fire and forget, without forcing the async keyword up the call stack.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva: That's an incorrect solution. Feel free to post your own question.

Comment: @StephenCleary there should be a badge for getting accepted answer with later reply than Jon Skeet