# How to change async method call to prevent forcing async up the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, servicebus

If I need to call a method that in turn calls some async method internally, as a fire and forget operation, how can I prevent this call from forcing the "async" to need to be used up the call stack to say...an MVC controller?

For example:  My MVC Controller (not async) calls a business layer method, which in turn calls the Windows Azure Service Bus QueueClient.SendAsync(BrokeredMessage), to drop a message in a queue, but doesn't need to wait for it to complete.

Typically, when this controller action is invoked, the compiler will throw an error that the async operation cannot be started at this time.

I know that instead of awaiting or just invoking the SendAsync() method, I could follow it up with ContinueWith(), in order to execute code on the callback of the async operation, but I've been told this not a correct solution. (see responses to [Calling async method in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13647346/5101))

Would someone care to enlighten me on the best way to fix this scenario?  And tell me why the ContinueWith() approach is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> calls the Windows Azure Service Bus QueueClient.SendAsync(BrokeredMessage), to drop a message in a queue, but doesn't need to wait for it to complete.

First, I'd reconsider this assumption. If you want a fully reliable system, the action *should* wait for the message to be sent to the bus. Note that this is usually a fast operation (100ms).

> Typically, when this controller action is invoked, the compiler will throw an error that the async operation cannot be started at this time.

Ensure that you do not have any `async void` methods or [EAP method calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I would be very surprised if the Azure storage library causes that exception.

> Would someone care to enlighten me on the best way to fix this scenario? And tell me why the ContinueWith() approach is not correct?

The best solution is to embrace `async`. `ContinueWith` could work but is dangerous to use (it has lots of parameters, some of which have unsafe default values); `await` is practically the same as `ContinueWith` but without the dangerous defaults.

---

However, if 100ms is truly unbearable, and you are willing to give up reliability (in this case, that means you accept the fact that some messages *may not get sent to the bus* even though the action completed successfully so the client *thinks that they did*), then you can use the [`BackgroundTaskManager` from my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) to minimize the chance of lost messages.

Comment: I understand the first point you make about reliability when dropping messages.  I am likely not going to change my MVC controller to async at this point, or change the action to an async method, because that assumes I'm changing the interface of the business layer to an async method (embracing async all the way).

If I use ContinueWith() but use the overload to pass in CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default, should that not take care of the "dangerousness" of the default ContinueWith() overload and give me the reliability aspect?

Comment: Specifying all the parameters will take care of the "dangerousness", but will **not** give you the reliability. What you suggested is essentially the same as calling `Task.Run`. If you don't want to change your business layer (etc.) to be async, then you should just call `Send` instead of `SendAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

An MVC controller method handles an HTTP request and sends back the corresponding HTTP response to the client. If I understood your question correctly, you want to call a fire-and-forget method from your async MVC controller method, then proceed with the HTTP response delivery, so the fire-and-forget method doesn't hold the response.

Indeed, you cannot fire it from with your controller method this way, without awaiting its results. I.e., you could, but if your ASP.NET application would be restarted, or the IIS server taken out of the farm, your `ContinueWith` callback would never be called. So, you woudn't know if the request had ever reached the Windows Azure Service.

One approach to solve this is to run a helper Web API or WCF service on the same host, or on another host on the same network (so the turn-around for a service call would be really quick). It can be a self-hosted service. You'd call this helper service from your MVC controller just to **queue** the fire-and-forget operation. You'd `await` the result of this call, but it's not a problem in this case, because both the caller and the callee of this operation would exist on the same network.

This way, the original MVC HTTP response won't be put on hold. Inside the helper service, you'd then do `await QueueClient.SendAsync()` to call Windows Azure Bus and process the result of this operation accordingly.

Comment: I think that spinning up web API and changing the controller call from an internal business layer to a HTTP endpoint facade of the same business layer is overkill...and not something I'm willing to do.

Also, my controller is not async.  It simple calls into a business layer DLL that in turn leverages the Azure SB API which has async methods.  I don't want to change my controller to async, or have async actions in the controller.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva, it certainly wasn't clear to me from the question that your controller is not asynchronous.

Comment: apologies if I wasn't clear enough, but I appreciate your response!